# How do I know which replicaset has live traffic with blue/green deployment with validation in Spinnaker?

Tags: replicaset, spinnaker, blue-green-deployment

I am trying to use blue/green with validation deployment in Spinnaker. The Spinnaker documentation recommends I used replicasets and add the annotation: strategy.spinnaker.io/max-version-history: '2' to control cleanup for my old replicasets. But what if I have a failed deployment? Then when I redeploy, I will have created a 3rd replicaset and the version history will delete my oldest one, which is current live traffic.

Even if I increase the max number to 100, what happens if I fail 101 times. How do I protect my live traffic and still clean up unused replicasets?